# Перенос структуры таблицы

Tags: html

Есть 2 таблицы, у первой такая структура:

```
<div class="trading__market-table">
                                    <div class="trading__market-table_vkl">
                                        <div class="trading__market-table-row" id="CoinProd_BTC" name="CoinID_BTC" onclick = 'ChangeCoinProdBuySell("CoinID_BTC");'>
                                            <div class="trading__market-table-wrap">
                                                <div class="trading__market-table-circle trading__market-table-circle--green" name="Point_BTC" onclick='ChangeColorGreenPoint("Point_BTC");'></div> <!-- green -->
                                                <div class="trading__market-table-coin">BTC</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="trading__market-table-price"></div>
                                            <div class="trading__market-table-volume"></div>
                                            <!--<div class="trading__market-table-change"></div>-->
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="trading__market-table-row" id="CoinProd_ETH" name="CoinID_ETH" onclick = 'ChangeCoinProdBuySell("CoinID_ETH");'>
                                            <div class="trading__market-table-wrap">
                                                <div class="trading__market-table-circle trading__market-table-circle--green" name="Point_ETH" onclick='ChangeColorGreenPoint("Point_ETH");'></div> <!-- green -->
                                                <div class="trading__market-table-coin">ETH</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="trading__market-table-price"></div>
                                            <div class="trading__market-table-volume"></div>
                                            <!--<div class="trading__market-table-change"></div>-->
                                        </div>
```

2ая таблица:

```
<div class="table__content">
                <table>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Time</th>
                      <th>Price(USD)</th>
                      <th>BTC</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>16:30:21</td>
                      <td>7.481,21</td>
                      <td>0.009923</td>
                    </tr>

                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
```

Как можно перенести структуру первой таблицы во 2ую?

Скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var MarcetTableRow;
var CoinVal="USD";
var CoinProd="BTC";
var result_Exchange_Rates={};
var Arr_Coins_Names=[];
var Arr_Coins_Val_Names=[];
var Volume_Coins={};
    window.onload = function() {
        result_Exchange_Rates.Exchange_Rates=null;
        result_Exchange_Rates.History_Rates=null;
        Max_Id_Ord=0;

        MarcetTableRow=document.getElementsByClassName('trading__market-table-row');

        ChangeCoinProdBuySell("CoinID_"+CoinProd);

        document.getElementById("Book_Total").innerHTML = "TOTAL (USD)";
        document.getElementById("Book_Price").innerHTML = "PRICE (USD)";
        document.getElementById("Book_Amount").innerHTML = "AMOUNT ("+CoinProd+")";

    };  
function ChangeCoinProdBuySell(NameCoinProd){
    for (var i=0; i<MarcetTableRow.length; i++) {
        MarcetTableRow[i].classList.remove('trading__market-table-row-active');
    }
    var Coin_Elements=document.getElementsByName(NameCoinProd);
    for (var i=0; i<Coin_Elements.length; i++) {
        Coin_Elements[i].classList.add('trading__market-table-row-active');
    }
    CoinProd=NameCoinProd.split('_')[1];
    document.cookie = "CoinProd="+CoinProd;
    document.getElementById("AmountValBuy").innerHTML = CoinProd;
    document.getElementById("Book_Amount").innerHTML = "AMOUNT ("+CoinProd+")";
    showGraph(CoinProd);
}

function get_cookie ( cookie_name ){
  var results = document.cookie.match ( '(^|;) ?' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)' );

  if ( results )
    return ( unescape ( results[2] ) );
  else
    return null;
}

function Change_Volume_Coins(){
    var Ord_Row=document.getElementsByClassName('orders__table-row');
    for (var j=0; j<Arr_Coins_Names.length; j++) {
        var vol=0;
        for (var i=0; i<Ord_Row.length; i++) {
            if (Ord_Row[i].querySelector('.orders__table-pair').innerHTML==Arr_Coins_Names[j]+'/'+CoinVal){
                vol+=Number(Ord_Row[i].querySelector('.orders__table-amount').innerHTML)
            }
        }
        (document.getElementById('CoinProd_'+Arr_Coins_Names[j])).querySelector('.trading__market-table-volume').innerHTML=vol.toFixed(7)
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Вот, как-та так - берём и переносим... Вы бы что-то нормальное добавили, с данными, в первую таблицу.. Или хотя бы скрин киньте как она должна выглядеть

Comment: @InDevX  Меня интеренсует как перенести все классы, учитывая, что 1ая таблица сверстана дивами

Comment: это так же зависит от стилей, они вообще могут быть прописаны аля `div.trading__market-table`.. слишком много переменных и слишком мало информации предоставляете..

Comment: @InDevX будут ли все функции, которые привязаны здесь <div class="trading__market-table-row" id="CoinProd_BTC" name="CoinID_BTC" onclick = 'ChangeCoinProdBuySell("CoinID_BTC");'> работать также, если перенести их так:  <tr id="CoinProd_BTC" name="CoinID_BTC" onclick = 'ChangeCoinProdBuySell("CoinID_BTC");'>

Comment: Киньте код функции, так-то могут работать, могут и не работать, смотря что и как они делают

Comment: @InDevX прикрепил скрипт

Comment: Должны работать, не вижу тут привязки к дивам или другим эл-там